# Existence of a sigma-measurable function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A)$ be a measurable space.

Let $C$ be a subspace of $X$ which does not contain any element of $\mathcal A$. Why is a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ $\sigma(\mathcal A \cup$ {$C$}$)$-measurable, iff there exists $\mathcal A$-measurable functions $f_1, f_2: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f = f_{1} \chi_{C} + f_{2} \chi_{C^C}$?

Comment: Can we see your attempt please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable then
the functions $f\chi_{C}$ and $f\chi_{C^{\complement}}$ are $\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$-measurable.

This because $f,\chi_{C},\chi_{C^{\complement}}$ are evidently $\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$-measurable
functions, and in general the product of two $\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$-measurable
functions is again a $\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$-measurable
function.

Further it is evident that $f=f\chi_{C}+f\chi_{C^{\complement}}$
so this proves one side.

If converversely $f=f_{1}\chi_{C}+f_{2}\chi_{C^{\complement}}$ where
$f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are $\mathcal{A}$-measurable and $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
is a Borel set then $f_{1}^{-1}\left(B\right),f_{2}^{-1}\left(B\right)\in\mathcal{A}$
and consequently $f_{1}^{-1}\left(B\right)\cap C,f_{2}^{-1}\left(B\right)\cap C^{\complement}\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$
so that: $$\left(f_{1}^{-1}\left(B\right)\cap C\right)\cup\left(f_{2}^{-1}\left(B\right)\cap C^{\complement}\right)\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$$

Now observe that: $$f^{-1}\left(B\right)=\left(f_{1}^{-1}\left(B\right)\cap C\right)\cup\left(f_{2}^{-1}\left(B\right)\cap C^{\complement}\right)$$
so actually it has been proved that $f^{-1}\left(B\right)\in\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$.

This works for any Borel set $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ and we conclude that $f$ is $\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\cup\left\{ C\right\} \right)$-measurable.